# Why negativeButton is "invisible"?

Tags: java, android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I'm trying to build an app with biometric authentication (Fingerprint) and I'm having some troubles with the negative button.
The button works, but for some reason is completely invisible.
[This is how the app shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrDwV.jpg)

[And this is how it sees when you prees the button. As you can see, it exist, but i don't know how to make it visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8e2z.jpg)

I'm using BiometricPrompt and BiometricManager in Java.

Edit: It seems that the button shows normally in any other phone that isn't mine
I'm using a Xiaomi Redmi Note 8.

However this is the code that I'm using:

```
private void initViews()
{
    biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this);
    passwordEditText=findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    loginButton=findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
            Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.");
            break;
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
            Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.");
            break;
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:
            Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.");
            break;
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:
            Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "The user hasn't associated " +
                    "any biometric credentials with their account.");
            break;
    }
    executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
    biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(EnterYourPassActivity.this,
            executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                          @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            if(errString.equals("Use account password"))
            {
                passwordEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("MY_APP_TAG",""+errString);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Authentication error: " + errString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Authentication succeeded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent seeingFiles = new Intent(EnterYourPassActivity.this, SeeingFilesActivity.class);
            startActivity(seeingFiles);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
            .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Use account password")
            .build();

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can set a buttons *visibility* through xml (`visible` property if I remember correctly) or in code (`button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`). Lastly do checkout if the button's color is the same color as the area in the background.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding code of what youv done like how you have build the dialog .see if this works for you : dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setBackground(R.color.yourcolor);

Comment: Thanks, the post is edited already

Comment: I see the same problem on a Samsung Galaxy S8, Android 9. 
There is no dialog object to manipulate so it's unclear to me how to access this button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change negativeButton text in this way:

**Important** - put string into resources:

```
    <string name="negative_button_text"><![CDATA[<font color=\'#48a134\'>Your text at given color</font>]]></string>
```

As you can see, you can set text color in hex.
Now put negativeText into BiometricPrompt as follows:

```
val negativeButtonText = getString(R.string.negative_button_text)
val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
    .setTitle("title")
    .setDescription("description")
    .setNegativeButtonText(fromHtml(negativeButtonText))
    .build()

fun fromHtml(html: String): Spanned {
    return HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
}
```

In given example negativeText is green and prompt looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7zJe.png).